# ANTLR v4 operator precedence problem using parentesis

Tags: antlr, antlr4, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree, operator-precedence

I have to parse this definition of var agenda (it's Z language):

```
agenda : \nat \cross \nat \pfun \nat
```

I want \cross have precedence over \pfun, so if i code:

```
typeNorm returns [TreeNode node]
        :   a=typeNorm '\\cross' b=typeNorm
        |   a=typeNorm \pfun b=typeNorm
```

it works, produces agenda AST:

```
                    \pfun
      \cross                   \nat
\nat          \nat
```

but, if i code:

```
typeNorm returns [TreeNode node]
            :   a=typeNorm ('\\cross' b=typeNorm)
            |   a=typeNorm \pfun b=typeNorm
```

produces:

```
                    \cross
      \nat                   \pfun
                         \nat       \nat
```

I need to understand why parentesis change precedence

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this.

For the input `a \pfun b \pcross c`, both:

```
typeNorm
 : typeNorm '\\pcross' typeNorm
 | typeNorm '\\pfun' typeNorm
 | ID
 ;

ID     : [a-zA-Z]+;
SPACES : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

and:

```
typeNorm
 : typeNorm ('\\pcross' typeNorm)
 | typeNorm '\\pfun' typeNorm
 | ID
 ;

ID     : [a-zA-Z]+;
SPACES : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

the following parse tree is produced:

[image]

Tested with ANTLR 4.9.2 and 4.9.3.